# SQL join between two tables to get all the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a simple query but I have no luck getting the right output

I have two tables

[Stores]

StoreID
StoreName

[Inventory]

ItemID
StoreID
Quantity

Store has all the stores (1-5) and Inventory has all the items (1-20000) with quantities currently located in the stores.

If I do the outer join i get

```
StoreID ItemID  Quantity
1       1       5
2       1       4
1       2       1
1       5       0
```

What I am trying to get is list of all the stores with all the items no mater if the Quanty is null. For example

```
StoreID ItemID  Quantity
1       1       5
2       1       4
3       1       NULL
4       1       NULL
5       1       NULL
1       2       1
2       2       NULL
3       2       NULL
4       2       NULL
5       2       NULL
```

How can I accomplish this ? Thanks in advance

Here is what I tried

Objekti=Stores, Artikli=Products, SubQuery=Inventory - just translation

[image: Query]

But I get duplicated results

[image]

Here is the query from above

```
SELECT
  Objekti.ObjekatID
 ,Objekti.ObjekatNaziv
 ,Artikli.SifraKase
 ,SubQuery.Slobodno
FROM dbo.Objekti
CROSS JOIN dbo.Artikli
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    Artikli.SifraKase
   ,Stanje2_PoObjektu.Slobodno
   ,Stanje2_PoObjektu.ObjekatID
  FROM dbo.Artikli
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Stanje2_PoObjektu
    ON Artikli.SifraKase = Stanje2_PoObjektu.SifraKase) SubQuery
  ON Artikli.SifraKase = SubQuery.SifraKase
```

Comment: Please be more precise: Show sample data of the tables and show the query you tried. What does "If I do the outer join" mean?

Comment: Have you tried a `left join` on `ItemID`. Your current attempt/script would be very helpful.

Comment: You have no Store 3 in your table. Why make it up?

Comment: Your design is flawed, you should have a Store table, a **Product** table and and Inventory table. Then you would would cross join Store + Product and left join inventory. And with your current desiyiu haven't told us whether Yiu store a zero quantity inventory record for every product ahaisyevery store

Comment: I need to have store 3 because I need to use this in another query where I have orders for store 3. I can have an Order in store 3 for some item that I don't currently have on stock. In that way I would have one more column Ordered that would have Quantity with null

Comment: You can do this by defining a subselect or common-table-expression that selects distinct itemIDs. You can then cross join the store table to that itemID list before left joining to the inventory.

Comment: As already said, you should provide sample data of your tables rather than only showing results of queries.

Comment: @DaleK I do have a Products table and I tried your suggestion now but I get duplicate results. I get StoreID and ItemID 3 times

Comment: I updated the question with additional information

Comment: And please don't use images

Comment: I added a query in the question

Comment: Your query has some weird inner join, just left join inventory onto your cross join. Also I highly recommend *short* table aliases to make your query more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the product table for this query. I assume there is information in it that could be needed for other queries but based on the result set, this one only needs the ItemID. That can be pulled from the inventory table.

```
SELECT 
      Stores.StoreID
    , Stores.StoreName
    , Inventory.ItemID
    , Inventory.Quantity
 FROM Stores
 LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Stores.StoreID = Inventory.StoreID
 ORDER BY Inventory.ItemID ASC, Stores.StoreID ASC
```

If product is needed, I would left join it to Inventory.

```
SELECT 
      Stores.StoreID
    , Stores.StoreName
    , Inventory.ItemID
    , Product.ProductName
    , Inventory.Quantity
 FROM Stores
 LEFT JOIN Inventory ON Stores.StoreID = Inventory.StoreID
 LEFT JOIN Product ON Product.ItemID = Inventory.Item.ID
 ORDER BY Inventory.ItemID ASC, Stores.StoreID ASC
```

This approach could return a lot of nulls if your tables are missing data but it should take care of your duplicate issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
user_register.userid,user_register.emailid,user_register.password,user_register.createdon,user_register.updatedon,user_details.firstname,user_details.lastname,user_details.mobileno,user_details.countryid,master_country.countryname,master_state.statename,user_details.stateid,user_details.city,user_details.usertypeid,master_usertype.usertype,user_details.profileimg from user_register join user_details join master_country join master_state join master_usertype on user_register.userid=user_details.userid and master_country.countryid=user_details.countryid and user_details.stateid=master_state.stateid and user_details.usertypeid=master_usertype.usertypeid where user_register.userid=?
```

Comment: Wow - no idea how that relates to the question. I highly recommend learning how to format a query so it's readable.